# Moving elements in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, cycle

I have 2d array filled with random numbers.

For example:

```
#define d 4

int main(void)
{
int a[d][d];
int primary[d], secondary[d];
size_t i, j;

srand(time(NULL)); /* fill array with random numbers */
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
    a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
  }
```

How to change diagonals . For example :

```
1 0 0 0 2        2 0 0 0 1
0 3 0 4 0        0 4 0 3 0
0 0 5 0 0   to   0 0 5 0 0
0 6 0 7 0        0 7 0 6 0
8 0 0 0 9        9 0 0 0 8
```

Task is to print random matrix of d size then change diagonals placement using cycle and print it again.However i`m not getting how cycle should look like.

Appreciate any hints or examples.

Comment: Use the same logic that you used to fill up the matrix, but with reversed loops and printing instead of set it up with a random value.

Comment: What do you mean by "using cycle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop while `j < d / 2` and then swap the values:

```
for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < d / 2; j++) {
        int temp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i][d - j -1];
        a[i][d - j -1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сan u explain what d/2 is doing?  And yeah its worked fine.

Comment: Divides d by 2 :), Do it with paper and pencil, you only need to swap until the middle giving the left and right offsets.